# Jenkins - Promoted Builds & Git

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, promotions

Is it possible to get the Jenkins Promoted Builds plugin to invoke a second job, which in turn builds from the *commit that was promoted*, rather than from the latest revision?

So the flow would be something like this:

- Commit A is made
- 'Dev' job performs build #1 from commit A
- Commit B is made
- 'Dev' job performs build #2 from commit B
- User manually promotes Dev #1
- 'Staging' job builds #1 from commit A (not B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in Jenkins that prevents this from being possible.

Normally one would:

- Install Promoted Builds plugin
- Install Parameterized Trigger
- Configure Job Dev to be promotable, specifying "*Trigger/call builds on other projects*", then setting parameter of "*Pass-through Git Commit that was built*"

Sadly there appears to be [a bug in the Promoted Builds plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/VFQsTn1lAF8/discussion) that means not all data are passed. There [exists a fix](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin/pull/12), but it appears to be awaiting integration.

I've raised a [ticket in Jenkins' JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14145) which y'all should vote on if you're also afflicted by this issue.